# Reverse harem manhwa where the female lead is summoned to another world

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

Does anyone know a reverse harem manhwa where a girls from Earth are summoned to another world because the other world does not have any females? Girls give the guys mana by having ***. It's not a hentai manhwa though. It's been a while since I read it and I can't remember the title.

Comment: If someone posts the correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*[Bride of Elysion](https://www.anime-planet.com/manga/bride-of-elysion)*

[image: Front image of Bride of Elysion]

> Ina Yoo, an average girl from earth, gets summoned to a fantasy world called Elysion. Elysion summons females from other worlds and the men of Elysion treat the women with the utmost respect and try to charm the women. When the men of Elysion mate with the women, mana from the men are passed on to the women and the women can use this mana as their own power. Ina is courted by many men of the top hierarchy of Elysion population and her choice affects her political powers in Elysion. As Ina rises in social political status with her increasing magical powers, a rival, Roxanne, appears and tries to overthrow Ina's influence in Elysion by creating riots. Ina now has to calm the riots, but can she do so through her husbands and boyfriends...?

Found with a search for `manhwa isekai reverse harem mana sex`.

Comment: Thank you so much!!